# Where have I gone wrong in my determination of dynamic viscosity?

Tags: experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, viscosity

For my high school physics project I am trying to determine the viscosity of water at different temperatures using an oscillating spring. However, for water at $21^oC$ I am getting a value of about $0.15Ps$ when it should be about $0.001Ps$. If anyone could point out what I have done wrong it would be greatly appreciated!

My setup is a spring suspended from a fixed point. On the end of the spring is a total mass of 0.45kg; this is made up of some masses attached to the end of the spring and a small metal ball which is dangling from the masses by some fishing line. This metal ball is submerged in water, and when the spring oscillates the ball remains submerged. When the spring is oscillating, I observe it using a camera set up some distance away. I have a scale behind the oscillating spring so that when I play the video from the camera back I can use a reference point on the suspended masses to find the amplitude of each oscillation.

I then use this to plot a graph of amplitude against time over 20s. Since I am only plotting amplitude against time rather than displacement against time, I end up with a graph which is described by the exponential decay $y=Ae^{\frac{-b}{2m}t}$ instead of $y=Ae^{\frac{-b}{2m}t}\cos(\omega t+\Theta)$. In the case of my graph ($y=Ae^{\frac{-b}{2m}t}$), y is amplitude, m is mass, t is time, A is a constant and b is the coefficient in the formula $F_{frictional}=-bv$ where F is the frictional force acting on the ball and v is the velocity of the ball.

So my graph of amplitude against time for water of temperature $21^oC$ has the equation $y=0.056e^{-0.031t}$. Therefore:$$0.031=\frac{b}{2m}$$ $$b=0.0279kgs^{-1}$$ Using m as 0.45kg (I am not sure if b should be given units). I am assuming that all damping force can be attributed to the metal ball's motion through the water eg. air resistance on the masses/spring is negligible. The diameter of the metal ball is 0.0191m, and I used this and an approximation of its maximum velocity to calculate Reynold's Number, which I found to be less than 10 and so showed that Stoke's Law can be used in this situation. Applying Stoke's Law: $$F_{frictional}=6\pi\eta rv$$ (Where r is the radius of the metal ball and $\eta$ is the dynamic viscosity of the medium it is moving through) $$\frac{F_{frictional}}{v}=6\pi\eta r$$ $$b=6\pi\eta r$$ (I have omitted the negative sign as it is just showing that F and v are in opposite directions) $$\eta=\frac{b}{6\pi r}$$ $$\eta=\frac{0.0279}{6\pi *0.00955}$$ $$\eta=0.155 Ps$$ Which is obviously incorrect for water at $21^oC$. I know my method is not going to be that accurate, but it just seems really far off. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

I am comparing my values of viscosity with the values here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-dynamic-kinematic-viscosity-d_596.html

Edit: Now I know my Reynold's Number calculation is wrong, is there any way I can calculate viscosity when my Reynold's Number is above 10 (about 8000)?

Comment: Can you provide the details of your calculation that the Reynolds number is 10 at most? This seems very low for water.

Comment: Whatever metal your ball is made out of, it seems to be more than 6 times denser than gold.  With diameter 0.0191 m and mass of 0.45 kg, it must be an exotic material.

Comment: Chemomechanics - yeah I've realised I made a big mistake in my Reynold's Number calculation. I used the mass density of water in g/cm^3 rather than in kg/m^3... So my actual value for Reynold's Number is almost 8000... Thanks for pointing that out. Ben51 - 0.45kg is the mass of the metal ball + the masses suspended from the end of the spring. The mass of the metal ball by itself is less than 0.05kg.